# python - create multiple dataframes in loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, dataframe

I collected data from several excel files with code as follows:

```
path_list=[list_of_paths]
data=[pd.read_excel(path) for path in path_list]
```

Which gave me list of dataframes
Fortunately, It was only 16 files. So, I created manually separate dataframes. I wondered (and unsuccessfully searched) if there is any way to create them with some code?
I tried loop like this:

```
i=0
for df in data:
   i+=1
   'dataframe'+str(i)=pd.DataFrame(df)
```

but got error 'can't assign operator.

Could somebody help me in this issue?

Comment: Why not save them into dict

Comment: could you send some details?

Comment: Do you want them to be seperate dataframes or do you want to use them to generate one big dataframe?

Comment: If you want them in one big dataframe, this question sounds similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20906474/import-multiple-csv-files-into-pandas-and-concatenate-into-one-dataframe

Comment: @Maddo I want separate dataframe for each

Comment: What's wrong with just having a list of dataframes?

Answer (score 0):

There are couple things in your code:

1. `pd.read_excel(path)` already gives you a data frame. So there is no point doing `pd.DataFrame(df)` later.
2. `'dataframe' + str(i)` is a string, which is immutable. You can't assign some value to it. You may look for `some_dict['dataframe' + str(i)] = df`. But what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: Ok, but still, this will be let's say modified list of dataframe. My goal is to analyze them separately. For example fill missings (diffent in each df), rename some columns (there are different columns in some of them). How I could make this when I've got list of them and not each in separate dataframe?

Comment: What do you mean? Even with a list you can still do `data[i]` for `I` any number in the range.

Answer (score 0):

They're already in a list, so you can access each dataframe through simple list indexing:

```
data[0] # dataframe1
data[1] # dataframe2
```

If you're persistent in separating the concerns of each dataframe, then you can assign each to its own meaningful variable:

```
concern_one = data[0]
# proceed to process concern_one
```

Though if this is the case, then I think loading them all as a group makes little practical sense. I would opt to simply analyze each one individually.